# Recommend an open source VoIP project?

Tags: voip

Which do you think is the most stable and easy to get it going so far?

A link to download?

Comment: What kind of 'a VoIP project' do you mean? A VoIP client? A VoIP switch? A PSTN gateway? A SIP proxy?

What is the goal you want to achieve?

Comment: As Jacek said, more info please. Also, please make an effort to accept answers on the questions you ask.

Comment: I want to play with it without buying any hardware,so some simulating software is also needed

Answer (score 3):

[Virtualbox](http://www.virtualbox.org) to run a virtual machine with your Linux dist of choice. Assuming that you're in a windows environment and don't want to set up a physical machine.

Install [Asterisk](http://www.asterisk.org/) to get started with your VoIP server. Then you could use this client to make test calls with: http://www.3cx.com/VOIP/voip-phone.html

Answer (score 0):

Your question is lacking precision, even in the comments. "Play with it" still doesn't help understanding what you are looking for.

If you just want to try VoIP calls and see if you feel any difference with a regular (PSTN) phone line, you can use a VoIP client. There are tons of them, some commercial, some opensource. A non opensource one but free is X-Lite from Counterpath. It's well featured and easy to use.

You will also need a SIP line that usually comes (even if restricted) with all major triple play offers from ISPs.

If you are looking for something else than a client, here is a link that might help find your happiness: http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Open+Source+VOIP+Software
It has A LOT of information of various levels.